# Convert a Json-in-TEXT column to a real JSONB column

Tags: json, postgresql, ddl, jsonb

I have a TEXT column that actually contains a stringized JSON. Now I just want to convert it to a real JSONB. How to do this from `psql` console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all data is valid JSON, then this should work:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6437b895d0263a608227a1dc3fa01e2f)

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mytext_col TYPE jsonb USING mytext_col::jsonb;
```